# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'weasyprint.fonts'

Tags: python, python3

weasyprintのインストールは成功していると思うのですが、これでつまってしまいます。原因はなにがかんがえられますでしょうか。

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from weasyprint import HTML, CSS, default_url_fetcher
from weasyprint.fonts import FontConfiguration
from os import listdir
import sys
import shutil
import zipfile
import os
from inspect import currentframe, getframeinfo
import logging
```

Comment: このIssueが適用されるのでは？ [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'weasyprint.fonts' #1419](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/1419) つまりv53以後は`from weasyprint.text.fonts import FontConfiguration`とする必要があるのでは？

Comment: ありがとうございます、うごきました。自分もそのページみたのですが読んでませんでした。今後はみれるようにします。

Answer (score 1):

コメント指摘で解決したようなので、回答としておきます。

以下のIssueに書かれていた内容が当てはまるでしょう。
[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'weasyprint.fonts' #1419](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/1419)

> Had a similar issue. Apparently the import path has changed. This works for me:
>
> ```
> from weasyprint.text.fonts import FontConfiguration  # for weasyprint 53
> # from weasyprint.fonts import FontConfiguration  # for weasyprint 52
> ```

つまり`weasyprint`のv53以後は`from weasyprint.fonts import FontConfiguration`ではなく`from weasyprint.text.fonts import FontConfiguration`として間に`.text`を入れる必要があるということですね。